# Search columns and return number of cells containing "5" against colleague name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, formula

What I'm looking for is a formula that will do the following: (I'll be using the first row for this example):

- Firstly check cells E:J for cells containing a `5`.
- If all cells contain a `5` it will check the person's name and then add this to the box in column B against the correct name.
- If cells E:J have less than `5` in any of these cells it will disregard this row altogether.

To clarify, for `Shaun` it will count how many rows next to his name have `5`'s across the board then put the total number of rows fitting this criterion next to his name in Column B.

[image]

Comment: You say "count how many rows have 5's across the board" but no row has a 5 in column F, does that mean a completely empty row would count?

Comment: Column F has no digits as i would be copying data in from another source and i do not require this column so therefore deleted the data to attempt to show what i needed. I should have clarified so apologies. The answer that 'zx8754' has given has worked so all good. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a helper column:

Helper column, keep the name if the count of 5 equals to 5.
Enter below to `K2` and fill down.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E2:J2,5)=5,D2,"-")
```

Then we are counting how many times name appears in the helper column. Enter below to `B2` and fill down.

```
=COUNTIF($K$2:$K$11,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: as said, the F column can contain a 5-value which will introduce a possible bug when using countif for the helper column.

Comment: When i copy and paste the data into the sheet, column F does have data so to make things simple for users I got around this by adding a button at the top with a macro assigned that when pressed it erases all data in column F.

Answer (score 1):

Create formula in `K2` `(output the name if all values are 5)`

> =IF( AND(E2=5,G2=5,H2=5,I2=5,J2=5), D2, "")

Create the formula at `B2`which will `sum all occurrences of the names`

> =SUM(IF(K2:K11=A2,1,0))

(and press ctrl+shift+enter)

[image]

You maybe will need to replace , with ; (depends on your excel version).

Comment: Array formula is a bit overkill for this simple task, I would be happy if you used arrays without the helper column. Also, `AND(E2=5,G2=5,H2=5,I2=5,J2=5)` why not just `COUNTIF` ?

Comment: Agree re array formula, you can use `COUNTIF(K2:K11,A2)` as per your answer - but `AND` formula is a little different because F2 is excluded

Comment: I used the array formula, as an example. When I wrote my post you showed the countif and I wanted to show some other formula. And regarding the AND, if you are a coder you want to make the solution secure. The F column can make you problem if you dont take care of it.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind OK, point well made regarding column F, having said that, AND seems easy as there are only 5 columns, I can't imagine typing it all up if there were 50 columns... The solution would be to keep F column out of `COUNTIF` range, i.e.: have it for example as column C or L. Also, OP mentioned that "Column F has no digits".